# How to find occurrences of max number from an array in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am working on a voting system and I need to find the winner. But I am considering a scenario where two members have got the same vote and they both are winners. Hence, I want to return the details of both the winners.

My code does give the answer but I need a better way to do it. Please find the code below-

```
struct PoliticalParty{
string name;
uint256 voteCount;
}

PoliticalParty[] public winners;
uint256 public winnercount;
function declareWinner()public onlyOwner returns(PoliticalParty[]memory)
{
require(votingState==State.Canceled||block.number>endBlock);
if(votingState==State.Canceled){
revert("Voting is canceled.");
}

else{
string memory_name="";
uint256 max_count=parties[0].voteCount;

for(uint256i=1;i<parties.length;i++){
if(parties[i].voteCount>max_count){
max_count=parties[i].voteCount;
}
}

for(uint256j=0;j<parties.length;j++){
if(max_count==parties[j].voteCount){
_name=parties[j].name;
winners.push(PoliticalParty({name:_name,voteCount:max_count}));
winnercount++;
}
}
return winners;
}
}
```

Comment: hey @Isha Jha, welcome to stackoverflow. While asking questions, please keep in mind that other people might face the same issue in the future. So, explain your questions more clearly with a nicer format and keep google searchability in mind. And mark the answers as `accepted` when you think so.

Answer (score 1):

The question is crafted very poorly, however as far as i understand, you are looking for an algorithm to get the occurence count of the highest value.

If so, you could use something like this:

```
    function freqOfMaxNum(uint256[] memory arr)
        public
        pure
        returns (uint256, uint256)
    {
        uint256 max = 0;
        uint256 frequenceOfMax = 0;

        for (uint256 i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
                frequenceOfMax = 1;
            } else if (arr[i] == max) {
                frequenceOfMax++;
            }
        }

        return (max, frequenceOfMax);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I shall try to frame questions in a better way the next time. However, I could solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to optimize my code.

```
PoliticalParty[] public winners;
function declareWinner() public onlyOwner returns(PoliticalParty[] memory)
    {
        // the voting has been Canceled or Ended
       require(votingState == State.Canceled || block.timestamp > votingEndTime);
       if(votingState == State.Canceled){
           revert("Voting canceled.");
       }

       else{
       string memory _name="";
        uint256 max_count=0;
        
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < parties.length; i++) {
            if (parties[i].voteCount>max_count) {
                max_count = parties[i].voteCount;
                _name=parties[i].name;
                delete winners;
            winners.push(PoliticalParty({name: _name, voteCount: max_count}));
            }
            else if (max_count==parties[i].voteCount) {
                _name=parties[i].name;
                winners.push(PoliticalParty({name:_name, voteCount: max_count}));
                winnercount++;
            }
             
        }
        return winners;
       }
    }
```